# Slow HTTP proxy on certain ports

Tags: port, http-proxy, dedicated-server

I am using selenium chromedriver with HTTP proxies. I find that when I use them with port 80, I get decent performance. However, when I assign port 8085 I get a lot of slow page loads and timeouts. I am running this c# application on a few dedicated servers (winServ08), I find that on some servers I will get good performance but not on others from the same provider. I have contacted support for my dedicated server provider and also my proxy provider with no illumination. I am inexperienced with network diagnostics. How would I determine why this is occurring? I am forced to use 8085 by my provider and they're great value so I hope to stick with them. Thank you.

Comment: It may be that somewhere along the path somebody is shaping traffic and some ports (like `80`, `465` etc.) get higher priority. When this link gets saturated, connections on low-priority ports are throttled down at first. That's a guess. *Maybe* you could get some interesting results with `tcptraceroute`, I have never used it though.

Comment: all right much appreciated. First of many breadcrumbs to come no doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

@kamilmaciorowski is almost certainly correct - your ISP is prioritising traffic - and as your port is unknown it's most likely assumed to be torrenting traffic - which takes place on arbitrary ports) and is being thrown into the least important queue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If it's happening at the ISP level, is there anything I can do?